# Disappearing UIBarButtonItem images

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app that was recently released on the iOS App Store.  The main screen of the app has two button bars.  Each of the buttons has either an image or a text label.  The interface was developed with the XCode Storyboard editor.

One user sent me a screen shot that shows that all the image-based buttons have disappeared.  We've determined that the buttons are functional -- tapping where the button should appear has the desired effect, so the button is effectively present but invisible.  The text-based buttons appear and function normally.

The affected user is running the current version of iOS on an iPhone 6s.  Deleting the app and re-downloading had no effect.

The app has been downloaded a few hundred times, and several users have sent me positive feedback.  I've only got this one report of missing buttons.  Other than enabling/disabling depending on conditions, I'm not doing anything fancy with the button appearance.  I can't reproduce the problem on the emulator nor any of my hardware test devices.

Any clue what's happening here?

Comment: Maybe this user has some weird Accessibility option turned on? (I've no idea what it would be.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  it's the Bold Text option under Accessibility.  Thanks, Matt.

Now the next question is, is there anything I can do about it?  I know I can display a warning based on `UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled()`, but I would like to do better.  Is there any way to get the buttons to display when the option is turned on?  Is this a bug in the iOS implementation, or is it expected behavior?