# Bold Text accessibility option hides UIButtonBarItem graphics

Tags: ios, uibuttonbaritem

This is a follow-up to a question I asked last week [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620624/disappearing-uibarbuttonitem-images/53657622#53657622).  The main screen of my app has two button bars. Each of the buttons has either an image or a text label.  I've determined that when the user has the Bold Text Accessibility option enabled, the image buttons disappear from the screen. The buttons are functional -- tapping where the button should appear has the desired effect, so the button is effectively present but invisible. The text-based buttons appear and function normally.

Is this expected behavior, or is this a bug in the iOS implementation?  If it's a bug, is there a procedure to report it?  Is there a workaround?  My fallback solution is to display a warning based on `UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled()`, but I would like to do better.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the issue reported to me by one of my customers. I can replicate the issue on iOS12 however Apple appear to have fixed it in iOS13.

My workaround for iOS12 is to set the tintColor of the toolbar:

```
[toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

With the tintColor set the toolbar buttons are visible with Bold Text on.